# Property 'filteredUsers' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Props'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have no idea how to fix this error that is posted in the title. Why is it highlighting Userslist for me? Please help and explain how to fix this.
[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeK6T.png)

File Main:

```
import UsersList from '../UsersList';
import Debounce from '../DebounceInput';
import Header from '../Header';
import UsersProvider from "../../contexts/Users";

const Main:React.FC= () => {
    const [showUser, setShowUser] = useState("");
    return (
    <div>
        <div>
             <Header/>
        </div>
            <UsersProvider>
                <UsersList/>
                <Debounce onChange={setShowUser}/>
            </UsersProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Main
```

File Userslist:

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
type Props = {
    filteredUsers:Array<Person>;
}
type Person = {
    name:string;
    username:string;
}

const UsersList: React.FC<Props> = ({filteredUsers}) =>{

    return(
        <div className="ListHead"> 
            <ol className="list">
                {filteredUsers.map((Person) => (
                    <li key={Person.name}>
                        <span>{Person.name}</span>
                        @{Person.username}
                    </li>
            ))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    )}
export default UsersList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the prop `filteredUsers` to your `UsersList` component . when you are doing this

```
const UsersList: React.FC<Props>
```

you are telling to typescript `I expect the props for my UsersList component to be in the shape/type of Props`.

In Your Props type you have mentioned filteredUsers is a required Prop and it is of shape Persons[]. If you are not sure whether you will always pass the filteredUsers to the UsersList component then you can make it as an optional prop by adding `?`

```
type Props = {
    filteredUsers?:Array<Person>;
}
```

Now its not mandatory to pass the `filteredUsers` to your `UsersList` . But we need to pass an default argument to avoid breaking the app when there is no `filteredUsers` .

```
const UsersList: React.FC<Props> = ({filteredUsers = []}) =>{
```